# Footer is not at the all the way at the bottom whenever im in fullscreen (F11)

Tags: html, css

I have made footer for my website and it works fine until i press f11/go into fullscreen, where the footer is suddenly placed not all the way at the bottom but there is a space between my footer and the bottom of my page where there is only white/my background color. Shown in the pictures linked below:

Normal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxi35.png
In fullscreen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/405JV.png

html

```css
footer {
     background-color: #000000;
     border-color: #000000;
     position: relative;
     line-height: 10px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     bottom: 0px;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 50px;
     font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <footer>
        <a>text</a>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: use `position: fixed`. And make sure that that the rest of your content has a *minimum* height of 100vh (= full height of the viewport) minus the height of your footer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You almost have it. If you want it to always be at the end of the page (even with scrolling), use `position: absolute`. To avoid it covering content at the end of the scroll, give the `html` tag padding on the bottom.

```css
html {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}


footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <footer>
    <a>text</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that works but when im not in fullscreen and scroll all the way to the bottom it looks like this and clips over my box: https://imgur.com/a/CHxe55V

Comment: i see but it doesnt work for me still for some reason there must be something wrong with my code but is there a way to make the position absolute when the user goes in fullscreen trough css? because position relative works fine until i go in fullscreen and the position absolute only works when i am in fullscreen and not in normal screen

Comment: @pat, You can use [media queires](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to detect different screen sizes. Try using a margin-bottom along with padding-bottom to fix the issue

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to solve this.

You can use add the following to your footer :

```css
position : absolute;
bottom: 0;
left : 0;
width : 100%
```

The problem with this is that when the rest of the content on your page gets long enough to get to the footer's position, the footer would overlay it. You can solve this by adding a bottom margin to the last div before your footer that's at least the height of the footer.

Another way to deal with it is to give the body a minimum height of 100vh and either make it flex and give the footer a margin top of auto or give the footer a fixed height and give it a margin top of auto. Should work just as well.

(Quick tip if you didn't already know: there's footer tag in HTML that you could use instead of a div tag. It makes absolutely no difference but does provide semantic help for someone reading your code)

Answer (score -1):

The thing that most beginners tend not to realise is the fact that the footer is not always going to be at the bottom of the page you can check out alot of professional websites and you see thesame thing it only sticks to the bottom when two conditions are met
-you have sufficient content on your page
-there is no problem with your Web hosting

But if you really want it to always look like it's at the bottom there is a method I came up with when learning

Html

```
<body>
 <header>
  <h2>Header</h2>
 </header>
 <main>
  <h2>Main</h2>
 </main>
 <footer>
  <h2>footer</h2>
 </footer>
</body>
```

Css

```
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box
}
body{
 width:100%;
 min-height:100vh;
 background:black;
}
header,main,footer{
 width:100vw;
 text-align:center;
}
header{
 height:100px;
 background: white;
}
main{
 min-height:100vh;
 background: gray;
}
footer{
 background: black;
 height: 100px;
}
```

You can try it out in a new file and see how it works, hope it helps